# Can silverlight queue a list of files and post, when connection available, to a web service / url?

Tags: silverlight, file-upload, queue

I need to provide a way of users uploading multiple files (can be 10MB each) over Mac, PC and a mobile device (something with an SD slot).

The connection from the mobile device can be poor so I need to enable queuing of the files so they can be delivered when connection becomes available.

I am looking at Silverlight as a potential option using something like this example uses and sending over the files when a connection is available.
http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/out-of-browser/demo/

I have tried searching for silverlight articles but not found anything appropriate. What I am trying to avoid is writing multiple versions of the software for Mac+PC (browser) and mobile device.

Can silverlight provide this kind of functionality or is something I would have to approach differently?

Comment: How would you define a "mobile device"?  Currently its not possible to write a single version to cover all your platforms.  Even if you limit to WP7 as a "mobile device" it will need to be a separate app it could however share a significant chunk of code. Even then few if any current WP7 devices have an SD slot anyway.

Comment: Mobile device is flexible as we are yet to purchase. I'm thinking possibly windows based tablets or something with a full browser if possible. We do most of our dev in .NET for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight can be used to do that.
You don't need to use the out-of-browser functionality, silverlight gives you low-level control over sockets and threads.

For devices it's a different scenario, as AnthonyWJones points out.
There is a silverlight version for the nokia, but I've know idea if it is actively developed. The is also a c++ version for linux/meego, there is a mono version.
But all those are different versions.